# How do I escape a string for HTML?

Tags: dart

I have a string that might contain unsafe HTML. I want to escape the tags in the string, changing `<script>` to `&lt;script&gt;`

How can I do this with Dart?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [HtmlEscape](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_convert/HtmlEscape.html) from `dart:convert`.

```dart
import 'dart:convert' show HtmlEscape;

void main() {
  var unsafe = 'Hello <script>world</script>';

  var sanitizer = const HtmlEscape();

  print(sanitizer.convert(unsafe));
}
```

The above app prints:

```
Hello &lt;script&gt;world&lt;&#x2F;script&gt;
```

The default behavior is to escape apostrophes, greater-than/less-than, quotes, and slashes.

If you want to control what is escaped, you can create a new `HtmlEscape` with a [HtmlEscapeMode](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/dart_convert/HtmlEscapeMode.html).

For example, to escape only greater-than/less-than and slashes, try this:

```
var sanitizer = const HtmlEscape(HtmlEscapeMode.ELEMENT);
```

**Remember**, Dart automatically sanitizes strings before they get into HTML. So you may not need to manually escape the HTML script. If you call `element.setInnerHtml` with an unsafe string, it will get sanitized.

Comment: And what would be the opposite: parse a string containing HTML entities and get the clean string? Does not seem to be implemented: https://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/1.6/dart/sdk/lib/convert/html_escape.dart

Comment: **The fact that Element.setInnerHtml sanitizes by default generally does not mean that you do not need to escape output.**  The sanitizer will (hopefully) protect you from XSS _if_ you forget to escape your output, but will still produce malformed output.  You still need to escape for correct behavior; the sanitizer is a safety net.

Also worth noting: you can replace the sanitizer with a validator, which will cause an error rather than silently mangling the output.  This may be desirable, as it will a) alert you to an error in your program and b) not make it obvious that you forgot an escape.